# Show dynamic data in MVC Grid

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm working on MVC 4 based website. The requirement is to show data from DataTable into MVC gridview.

**(1)** Generally to show data in Mvc grid, we use to -

- Declare Model with properties name.
- Bind those properties to value from database.
- Finally bind that model to grid.

But in this case, we are aware of what column to be shown.

**(2)** Now what would need to be done when we are not aware of the columns. Or the number of columns to be shown would be decided by end user.

*Can anyone help me to fix this? A hint or suggestion to how to do would be suffice for me.*

Comment: show some code u have ?

Comment: Please check my answer and comment it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way I found as solution is to go as -

```
@model System.Data.DataTable 
@using System.Data; 

<h2>Report</h2> 

<table> 
<thead> 
<tr> 
@foreach (DataColumn col in Model.Columns)     
{          
    <th>@col.ColumnName</th> 
}     
</tr> 
</thead>         
<tbody> 
@foreach (DataRow row in Model.Rows)     
{         
    <tr> 
    @foreach (DataColumn col in Model.Columns)         
    {              
        <td>@row[col.ColumnName]</td> 
    }         
    </tr> 
}     
</tbody>
```

The code is been picked from article - [ASP.NET MVC: Simple view to display contents of DataTable](http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2011/11/19/asp-net-mvc-simple-view-to-display-contents-of-datatable.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you use `MVC web grid`

```
@{
        var grid = new WebGrid(ViewBag.RegisterItems);
        @grid.GetHtml(
               tableStyle: "webGrid",
               alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
               selectedRowStyle: "select");
    }
```

here `ViewBag.RegisterItems` is your data that show in grid.